# How do I plot a beautiful scatter plot with linear regression?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, python-ggplot

I want to make a beautiful `scatter plot` with `linear regression` line using the data given below. I was able to create a scatter plot but am not satisfied with how it looks. Additionally, I want to plot a `linear regression` line on the data.

My data and code are below:

```
x            y
117.00      111.0
107.00      110.0
77.22        78.0
112.00       95.4
149.00      150.0
121.00      121.0
121.61      120.0
111.54      140.0
73.00        72.0
70.47       000.0
66.3         72.0
113.00      131.0
81.00        81.0
72.00        00.0
74.20        98.0
84.24        90.0
86.60        88.0
99.00        97.0
90.00       102.0
85.00       000.0
138.0       135.0
96.00        93.0

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(plt.style.available)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
plt.style.use('ggplot')

data = np.loadtxt('test_data',  dtype=float, skiprows=1,usecols=(0,1))

x=data[:,0]
y=data[:,1]
plt.xlim(20,200)
plt.ylim(20,200)

plt.scatter(x,y, marker="o",)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Other than the part about adding the linear regression, this is a pretty subjective question. Beauty is in the eye of the beholder, after all. You don't say *what* is wrong with the plot you can produce and what you would like to improve

Comment: You should specify clearer what you consider "beautiful". It is very subjective.

Answer (score 4):

Please check the snippet. You can use `numpy.polyfit()` with degree=1 to calculate slope and y-intercept of line to `y=m*x+c`
[image: graph]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
data = np.loadtxt('test_data.txt',  dtype=float, skiprows=1,usecols=(0,1))
x=data[:,0]
y=data[:,1]

plt.xlim(20,200)
plt.ylim(20,200)

plt.scatter(x,y, marker="o",)

m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
plt.plot(x, m*x + b)

plt.show()
```

**Edit1:**
Based on your comment, I added more points and now graph seems like this and it seems it passes via points.

To set transparency to points you can use `alpha` argument . You can set range between 0 and 1 to change transparency. Here I set `alpha=0.5`

`plt.scatter(x,y, marker="o",alpha=0.5)`
[image: transparent]
**Edit2:** Based on @tmdavison suggestion
[image: graph2]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
data = np.loadtxt('test_data.txt',  dtype=float, skiprows=1,usecols=(0,1))
x=data[:,0]
y=data[:,1]
x2 = np.arange(0, 200)
plt.xlim(20,200)
plt.ylim(20,200)

plt.scatter(x,y, marker="o",)

m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
plt.plot(x2, m*x2 + b)

plt.show()
```

Comment: is it possible to shift the linear regression line manually,,,when i add more data line doesnot pass through the points...

Comment: Line would pass through the points only as line is dependent on x and y array @sion thats why slope is calculated right which should pass through points.

Comment: anyway i need to plot transparent circle instead of solid circle...can it be done @Karthik

Comment: if you produce an independent `x` array for use in plotting the regression, you can define it to have starting an ending points that are not restricted to the data range

Comment: @KARTIK ok...its fine but i need to pass the  regression line from origin (0,0)....

Comment: @tmdavison can you please add a line on the code what you are saying actually correct and i need this kind of line

Comment: `x2 = np.arange(0, 200)` ... then, after using `polyfit`, `plt.plot(x2, m*x + b)`

Comment: @tmdavison getting error like thsis ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (200,) and (22,)

Comment: Ya @sion because there are 22 points in your text file where as x2 size is 200.. Give a step size of 10 to it `x2 = np.arange(0, 200,10)`

Comment: please add this line sir ....as i am new unable to do @Kartik sir

Comment: sorry, my mistake, should have been `plt.plot(x2, m*x2 + b)`

Comment: @tmdavison can you please add your line to the script...actually its not working....

Comment: @kartik would the line m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)  be m, b = np.polyfit(x2, y, 1) as suggested by @tmdavison(i am not sure,,,correct me if i am wrong)

Comment: is it possible to calculate correlation coefficient also in the above code @Karthik ...if so please please let me know....